# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to open gcov output in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using `Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)` and when I try to open the code coverage output generated on my program, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

The exact error is this one:

```
null
org.eclipse.jface
Error
Mon Jan 27 16:51:11 CET 2020
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.linuxtools.internal.gcov.action.OpenGCAction.open(OpenGCAction.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$12(WorkbenchPage.java:5504)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openExternalEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:5498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3309)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$9(WorkbenchPage.java:3216)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3177)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3167)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$1.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:850)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1165)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5663)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1386)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4931)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4472)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1474)
```

The only "external" plugin I use is `JSON Editor`, others only come from CDT.

Any idea?

Regards,

Comment: Possibly [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551011)

Comment: @greg-449 it doesn't correspond to my eclipse version but...